# Simple Harmonic Motion: Displacement formula

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, displacement

In Simple Harmonic Motion, the formula for Displacement is : $$x=A\mathrm{sin}(ωt-Φ)$$

So, if the value of  $Φ$ (*phi*) is not given in the question, should I use "Zero" as the value of *phi*? Or the value of *phi* would always be given in the question?

Answer (score 1):

This is more complicated than it seems on the surface. That's because the $\sin \theta$ and $\cos \theta$ are cyclic functions and there are 2 values of $\theta$ which give the same function value:$$\sin \theta = \sin(\pi-\theta).$$

The difference in the sine function of those two arguments is the $slope$ of the function, or in the case of simple harmonic motion (SHM), the velocity of the particle.

In order to know the initial phase of a particle in SHM, one needs to know not only the initial position, but the initial velocity. Consider the following setup:

> A mass is hanging from a spring and undergoing  oscillations of amplitude $A$ around its equilibrium point. At $t=0$ it's at equilibrium. Consider $up$ to be the positive $y$ direction. What equation of the form $y=A\sin(\omega t - \phi_0)$ will describe the motion?

In this case, you don't know whether to write
$$y=A\sin (\omega t)\text{ or } y=A\sin(\omega t - \pi)$$
because you haven't been told whether the mass is moving up or down at $t=0$. In the first case, the velocity at $t=0$ will be $\omega A$ and in the second, $-\omega A$.

The equation you give for simple harmonic motion results from a 2nd order differential equation. In order to apply it to a specific situation, one must have 2 specific conditions. Most often in introductory courses, those are initial position and initial velocity, but could be two specific positions at specific times.

Bottom line: You need more information about the motion of the mass before you arbitrarily choose $\phi_0=0$.

Answer (score 0):

The displacement at time $t=0$ is $x(0)=A\sin(-\Phi)$ where $A$ is the maximum displacement (the amplitude of the motion). So $\Phi$ is whatever phase angle gives the correct displacement at $t=0$. Formally,

$\displaystyle \Phi = -\sin^{-1}\left( \frac {x(0)} A \right)$

Often you may be told that $x(0)=0$, or you may be able to choose this condition yourself. In this case the object is at the mid-point of the motion at $t=0$ and so we have $\Phi=0$ and $x(t) = A \sin (\omega t)$.

Alternatively, if you know that $x(0)=A$ then $\Phi = -\frac \pi 2$ radians and $x(t) = A \sin(\omega t + \frac \pi 2) = A \cos(\omega t)$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's what you do in most cases. Obviously, depends on the question you have at hand and the definition of your coordinates. The phase phi just defines where your harmonic motion starts in the cyclic/swinging motion.

Just plug in some phi values and plot where you are in the simple harmonic motion and you will see.